# What's the meaning of "to" in this sign?

Tags: prepositions

On my way, I saw a big sign saying

> No **to** death penalty. Stop killing.

What's the meaning of **to**? The meaning of the sign is obvious but is it correct grammatically?

Comment: Signs don't use the correct English. They use [block language](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/grammar-practice-activities/2015/04/teaching-block-language-for-understanding-signs) . The "to" could refer to future time. Not so sure.

Comment: It's just a short version of "Say no to the death penalty".

Comment: If it's a "big" sign as you say, then the omission of "the" is unusual.  Ordinarily, even on a sign, you'd find space to be more grammatical: "No to *the* death penalty! Stop *the* killing!"

Comment: @user178049 "to" may not refer to future time because this country is executing Death penalty.

Comment: @Andrew Then, "No to the death penalty! Stop the killing!" is okay grammatically?

Comment: @TINGCHOE yes, it's standard imperative form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to), one of the possible usages of **to** is as a preposition meaning **in connection with**. The intended meaning is therefore

> Say no [in connection with] the death penalty

Is it grammatical? Well, it's missing **say** and **the**, but I don't think that the usage of **to** in this context is ungrammatical.

Comment: And to go one step farther, "Say no in connection with" means "oppose", so "Oppose the death penalty". Or in the original wording, replace "[say] no" with "be opposed", so it's equivalent to "Be opposed **to** the death penalty".

Comment: @fixer1234 Your comment is the easiest to understand. So "No to ~ " means "Oppose" in this sign.